# Placeholder in prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am using the below query in a prepared statement. Earlier I was using in procedure and using callable but now I am trying to use select query in jdbc prepared statement.

I know in preparestatement we write `insert into abc values(?,?,?);`

but here I have insert-select. same variable has been used many places. in this query I have 2 variable
`p_entity_type` and `p_update_mode`

```sql
INSERT INTO dynamicEntitynotgett
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    WITH data_view AS
     ( -- ITEM table
      SELECT 'ITEM' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              item_id data_id,
              item_name data_name,
              item_desc data_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM itemde
      UNION ALL
      -- ORG table
      SELECT 'ORG' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              org_id,
              org_name,
              org_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM orgde
        UNION ALL
      -- Feature table
              SELECT 'FEATURES' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              FEATURE_id data_id,
              FEATURE_NAME data_name,
              FEATURE_DESC data_desc,
              CREATION_DATE
        FROM FEATURESDE
      )
    SELECT upper(t.entity_type),
           t.data_id,
           t.data_name,
           t.data_desc,
           CASE lower(p_update_mode)
             WHEN 'INCREMENTAL' THEN
               CASE
                 WHEN t.creation_date > b.last_update_date THEN
                   'update'
                 WHEN t.creation_date < b.last_update_date THEN
                   'add'
               END
             WHEN 'full' THEN
              'add' 
           END action
      FROM data_view t
           LEFT JOIN ODA_REFRESH_DETAILS b
                  ON b.entity_type = t.entity_type
                 AND lower(p_update_mode )='incremental'
     WHERE (upper(p_entity_type) = t.entity_type OR p_entity_type IS NULL)
       AND (lower(p_update_mode) = 'full'
            OR (lower(p_update_mode) = 'incremental' AND b.entity_type IS NOT NULL)
           );
```

I will receive p_entity_type and p_update_mode from upper stream. which solution would be better? Resultset or Preparedstatement and how can I replace those values in query or use setXXX().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`namedParameterStatement`](http://javadox.com/org.sql2o/sql2o/1.3.0/org/sql2o/tools/NamedParameterStatement.html).  This would allow you to name the parameters.

I'm not exactly sure what you are referring to in your statement, but for instance, this line:

```
SELECT 'ITEM' entity_type
```

could be replaced with:

```
SELECT :ITEM as entity_type
```

where `:ITEM` is passed in just like a `?`, but could be used multiple times in the statement.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon . it is actually spring class. Do we have something like in vanilla java? I mean I am not  using spring framework.

Comment: @Shruti . . . It should be available directly -- named parameters are a very typical way of writing SQL.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Could you please help me on the same, please?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541003/creating-json-from-oracle-database-table

Comment: sir I am facing similar issues. this query works properly in procedure in pl/sql    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553154/placeholder-in-java-jdbc-using-preparestatement?noredirect=1#comment112380978_63553154