# Placeholder in java JDBC using preparestatement

Tags: java, jdbc, plsql, prepared-statement, resultset

I am using below query in preparedStatment. earlier I was using same query in PL/SQL procedure.

```
 INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    WITH data_view AS
     ( -- ITEM table
      SELECT 'ITEMENTITY' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              item_id data_id,
              item_name data_name,
              item_desc data_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM itemde
      UNION ALL
      -- ORG table
      SELECT 'ORGENTITY' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              org_id,
              org_name,
              org_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM orgde
        UNION ALL
      -- Feature table
              SELECT 'FEATUREENTITY' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              FEATURE_id data_id,
              FEATURE_NAME data_name,
              FEATURE_DESC data_desc,
              CREATION_DATE
        FROM FEATURESDE
      )
    SELECT upper(t.entity_type),
           t.data_id,
           t.data_name,
           t.data_desc,
           CASE UPPER(p_update_mode)
             WHEN 'INCREMENTAL' THEN
               CASE
                 WHEN t.creation_date > b.last_update_date THEN
                   'modify'
                 WHEN t.creation_date < b.last_update_date THEN
                   'add'
               END
             WHEN 'FULL' THEN
              'add' 
           END action
      FROM data_view t
           LEFT JOIN ODA_REFRESH_DETAILS b
                  ON b.entity_type = t.entity_type
                 AND lower(p_update_mode )='INCREMENTAL'
     WHERE (upper(p_entity_type) = t.entity_type OR p_entity_type IS NULL)
       AND (UPPER(p_update_mode) = 'FULL'
            OR (UPPER(p_update_mode) = 'INCREMENTAL' AND b.entity_type IS NOT NULL)
           );
```

Here 2 variables p_entity_type and p_update_mode I am receiving from upper stream. so I am using `?` to set these values.
my code is below. Whereever these variables are I put `?` and later set the corresponding values.

```
public int insertDataToGTT(String p_entity_type, String p_update_mode) throws Exception
{
    
    
    String sql= "INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
               (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
          WITH data_view AS( -- ITEM table
         SELECT 'ITEMENTITY' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
          item_id data_id,
          item_name data_name,
          item_desc data_desc,
          creation_date
                      FROM itemde
      UNION ALL
              -- ORG table
      SELECT 'ORGENTITY' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
          org_id,
          org_name,
          org_desc,
          creation_date
    FROM orgde
    UNION ALL
  -- Feature table
          SELECT 'FEATUREENTITY' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
          FEATURE_id data_id,
          FEATURE_NAME data_name,
          FEATURE_DESC data_desc,
          CREATION_DATE
    FROM FEATURESDE
  )
SELECT upper(t.entity_type),
       t.data_id,
       t.data_name,
       t.data_desc,
       CASE UPPER(?) //p_update_mode
         WHEN 'INCREMENTAL' THEN
           CASE
             WHEN t.creation_date > b.last_update_date THEN
               'modify'
             WHEN t.creation_date < b.last_update_date THEN
               'add'
           END
         WHEN 'FULL' THEN
          'add' 
       END action
  FROM data_view t
       LEFT JOIN ODA_REFRESH_DETAILS b
              ON b.entity_type = t.entity_type
             AND lower(?)='INCREMENTAL' //p_update_mode
 WHERE (upper(?) = t.entity_type OR ? IS NULL)  //p_entity_type(both places)
   AND (UPPER(?) = 'FULL'  //p_update_mode
        OR (UPPER(?) = 'INCREMENTAL' AND b.entity_type IS NOT NULL) //p_update_mode
       ) "

    PreparedStatement statement= connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.setString(1, p_update_mode);
    statement.setString(2, p_update_mode);
    statement.setString(3, p_update_mode);
    statement.setString(4, p_entity_type);
    statement.setString(5, p_entity_type);
    statement.setString(6, p_update_mode);

    
    int x=statement.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Number of rows inserted: "+x);
    return x;
}
```

It is giving me below exception. I checked parameter I have set proper. Actually I am using same values multiple places. is there anyway or any better way to do it?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:253)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:86)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:928)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1136)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3640)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1384)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3730)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3710)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1061)
    at oracle.apps.vof.v1.oda.dao.NewCallableDAONEW.insertDataToGTT(NewCallableDAONEW.java:106)
    at oracle.apps.vof.v1.oda.server.ODADynamicEntity.getDynamicEntities(ODADynamicEntity.java:143)
    at oracle.apps.vof.v1.oda.server.ODADynamicEntity.main(ODADynamicEntity.java:43)
Caused by: Error : 923, Position : 1028, Sql = INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    WITH data_view AS
     ( -- ITEM table
      SELECT 'ITEMENTITY' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              item_id data_id,
              item_name data_name,
              item_desc data_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM itemde
      UNION ALL
      -- ORG table
      SELECT 'ORGENTITY' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              org_id,
              org_name,
              org_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM orgde
        UNION ALL
      -- Feature table
              SELECT 'FEATUREENTITY' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              FEATURE_id data_id,
              FEATURE_NAME data_name,
              FEATURE_DESC data_desc,
              CREATION_DATE
        FROM FEATURESDE
      )
    SELECT upper(t.entity_type),
           t.data_id,
           t.data_name,
           t.data_desc,
           CASE UPPER(:p_update_mode) //p_update_mode
             WHEN 'INCREMENTAL' THEN
               CASE
                 WHEN t.creation_date > b.last_update_date THEN
                   'modify'
                 WHEN t.creation_date < b.last_update_date THEN
                   'add'
               END
             WHEN 'FULL' THEN
              'add' 
           END action
      FROM data_view t
           LEFT JOIN ODA_REFRESH_DETAILS b
                  ON b.entity_type = t.entity_type
                 AND lower(:p_update_mode)='INCREMENTAL' //p_update_mode
     WHERE (upper(:p_entity_type) = t.entity_type OR :p_entity_type IS NULL)  //p_entity_type(both places)
       AND (UPPER(:p_update_mode) = 'FULL'  //p_update_mode
            OR (UPPER(:p_update_mode) = 'INCREMENTAL' AND b.entity_type IS NOT NULL) //p_update_mode
           ), OriginalSql = INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    WITH data_view AS
     ( -- ITEM table
      SELECT 'ITEMENTITY' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              item_id data_id,
              item_name data_name,
              item_desc data_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM itemde
      UNION ALL
      -- ORG table
      SELECT 'ORGENTITY' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              org_id,
              org_name,
              org_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM orgde
        UNION ALL
      -- Feature table
              SELECT 'FEATUREENTITY' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              FEATURE_id data_id,
              FEATURE_NAME data_name,
              FEATURE_DESC data_desc,
              CREATION_DATE
        FROM FEATURESDE
      )
    SELECT upper(t.entity_type),
           t.data_id,
           t.data_name,
           t.data_desc,
           CASE UPPER(:p_update_mode) //p_update_mode
             WHEN 'INCREMENTAL' THEN
               CASE
                 WHEN t.creation_date > b.last_update_date THEN
                   'modify'
                 WHEN t.creation_date < b.last_update_date THEN
                   'add'
               END
             WHEN 'FULL' THEN
              'add' 
           END action
      FROM data_view t
           LEFT JOIN ODA_REFRESH_DETAILS b
                  ON b.entity_type = t.entity_type
                 AND lower(:p_update_mode)='INCREMENTAL' //p_update_mode
     WHERE (upper(:p_entity_type) = t.entity_type OR :p_entity_type IS NULL)  //p_entity_type(both places)
       AND (UPPER(:p_update_mode) = 'FULL'  //p_update_mode
            OR (UPPER(:p_update_mode) = 'INCREMENTAL' AND b.entity_type IS NOT NULL) //p_update_mode
           ), Error Msg = ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
    ... 17 more
```

same query is working properly in pl/sql

Comment: Aren't you setting more parameters than `?` are in the statement?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón thank you Herman. Is there any other way to set parameter when they are in large number and duplicate as well. here same parameter I am setting at multiplte placess. It is giving another error now. same query is working if I hardcode values or use in pl/sql

Comment: There is no other way in plain JDBC according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309984/2738151). The same answer suggests to use Spring's JDBC template.

Comment: What are the comments of "//p_update_mode" is doing inside the query string?  I don't think that's part of a standard sql.  I would remove all comments including those valid ones starting with "--" and then try again.